# Concatenate two date parts

Tags: sql, datetime, concatenation, converters

I'm trying to build a report based on a ticketing system we use. I'm quite new to SQL and just getting my head around it but the issue I am facing at the moment is trying to join two fields into a date. The data in the table is in displayed as `Month_Number` and `Year_Number`

I need to do a comparison with a datetime field to see if it is between the date range. I've searched a fair bit about concatenating the two fields I have into a date but unfortunately have come up short.

Comment: What type of database engine is this for? The dialect of SQL is important because some engines have true date datatypes while others do not. Date manipulation is very non-standard among common database engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to concatination for youe Month & Date Part.

```
declare @month varchar(10);
declare @year varchar(10)

set @month = 5
set @year = 2014
```

You can choose whatever you feel for you is the best

```
select @month+'-1-' +@year as Your_Date 
select '1-'+@month+'-' +@year as Your_Date 
select @year+'-'+@month+'-1' as Your_Date
```

**Output**

```
5-1-2014
1-5-2014
2014-5-1
```

To Retrieve the date from your Table in SQL you can do like this

```
select month_number+'-1-' +year_number as Your_Date 
from table_name
```

If you want to change the style of the displaying output then you can use `Convert` Function

Comment: I would recommend using an international date format. m-d-y is only valid in some regions (including the US) but in Europe, d-m-y is more common. To be safe, use yyyy-mm-dd which is an international standard.  I.E.  `@year + '-' + @month+'-1-' as Your_Date`

Comment: Note my comment above about the date format has nothing to do with the _display_ format, it is about the interpretation of the string by the database engine.  It is probably a better idea to avoid this type of string concatenation altogether and use a direct date function. For example `DateSerial` etc. But the existance of such a function will depend on the database engine.